# How can I rewrite the <?php ?> tags

Tags: php

I'm searching for a way to rewrite the php opening and closing tag. I prefer to just do something like "{ } or < ? ? >". Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question..can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I ca't seem to write php tags as it's being deleted.. Anyway, I want to skip the opening and closing tags of php.. the <?php and ?> I want to rewrite it to something like { } where '{' is the opening and '}' closing

Comment: And where do you want to write that ?

Comment: @DEarTh On my code, I'm looking for a way to do it more simpler.

Comment: And where would be your code, in some template engine or in some CMS/MVC ? You should elaborate that..

Comment: @DEarTh sorry bout that. In MVC I'm using. a friend gave me this tutorial on how to work with custom MVC and I'm just wondering if I can rewrite the PHP tags to lessen my work a bit.

Comment: You might be writing html+php, you could use template engine for that. Read about them there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short form of

```
<?php echo ?>
```

is

```
<?= ?>
```

The other way to do it to use something like template engine

<strike>check https://twig.symfony.com/</strike>

---

Check http://acmeextension.com/best-templating-engine/ for some like of the PHP template enginer

Comment: Can I rewrite it so somehing else? Is there some sort of way to set it to just use {  } ?

Comment: This is not true. The short form of `<?php echo '';  ?>` is `<?= ''; ?>`

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm talking about. I saw others use this on their MVC's and I'm not a backend person but just started to learn now. A friend told me to learn PHP and teach me to use my custom MVC and now I'm wondering how to use this same way.

Comment: @BryanRuiz Does it help you. Mark as solved if this solve your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAzizolAminuddin yes, it did. This is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Comment: "discouraged " so meaning I can't set it to anything I want then? Is it discouraged  for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change/rename the PHP opening tags.

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which are `<?php` and `?>` which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them. [...]
>   PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php